# Angular *Ngfor How to expand only one card at a time

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

`

```
<h1 style="margin-top: 24px"> Report</h1>
<mat-card class="mat-cards" *ngFor="let Nutrition of Nutrition; let i = index">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title
            ><h2>{{ Nutrition.name }}</h2></mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle class="data">{{ Nutrition.data }}</mat-card-subtitle>
        <mat-card-subtitle class="goal-range">{{ Nutrition.goalRange }}</mat-card-subtitle>
        <div class="column1">
            <mat-list role="list">
                <mat-list-item role="listitem" class="first-item">
                    <h3 matLine class="previous">Previous Values</h3>
                    <p class="prev" matLine style="font-size: 16px">
                        {{ Nutrition.previousValue }}
                    </p>
                    <p class="prev" matLine style="font-size: 16px">
                        {{ Nutrition.previousvalue1 }}
                    </p>
                    <p class="prev" matLine style="font-size: 16px">
                        {{ Nutrition.previousvalue2 }}
                    </p>
                </mat-list-item>
            </mat-list>
        </div>
    </mat-card-header>
    <div class="Content">
        <mat-card-content>
            <div [@collapse]="collapsed" class="expandable-content" *ngIf="i === index">
                <div class="column2">
                    <mat-list role="list" class="table-column" style="">
                        <mat-list-item role="listitem" class="first-item">
                            <h3 class="notes" matLine>{{ Nutrition.notes }}</h3>
                            <p class="description" matLine style="font-size: 16px w">
                                {{ Nutrition.Description }}
                            </p>
                        </mat-list-item>
                    </mat-list>
                    <mat-list role="list" class="table-column" style="" *ngIf="i === index">
                        <mat-list-item role="listitem" class="first-item">
                            <h3 class="related" matLine>Content</h3>
                        </mat-list-item>
                        <ul>
                          <li>{{Nutrition.related}}</li>
                          <li>{{Nutrition.related1}}</li>
                      </ul>
                    </mat-list>
                </div>
            </div>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </div>
    <mat-card-actions >
        <button *ngIf="collapsed" (click)="expand(i)" class="mat-button">Expand</button>
        <button *ngIf="!collapsed" (click)="collapse(i)" class="mat-button" >Collapse</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

`
The buttons will switch from Collapse when one card is expanded and each card is affected by one another when one cards is selected. If you expand one card the closed cards will say Collapsed while being closed.
`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, AUTO_STYLE } from '@angular/animations';
import { Nutrition } from './NutritionData';

const DEFAULT_DURATION = 200;
@Component({
    selector: 'app-nutrition-report',
    templateUrl: './nutrition-report.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./nutrition-report.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger('collapse', [
            state('false', style({ height: AUTO_STYLE, visibility: AUTO_STYLE })),
            state('true', style({ height: '0', visibility: 'hidden' })),
            transition('false => true', animate(DEFAULT_DURATION + 'ms ease-in')),
            transition('true => false', animate(DEFAULT_DURATION + 'ms ease-out')),
        ])
    ]
})
export class NutritionReportComponent implements OnInit {
    Nutrition;
    index;
    collapsed = true;

    constructor() {
        this.Nutrition = Nutrition;
    }

    toggle(index) {
        this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
        this.index = index;
    }

    expand(index) {
        this.collapsed = false;
        this.index = index;
    }

    collapse(index) {
        this.collapsed = true;
        this.index = index;
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

This is the Ts file where the animation and functions are taking place for the buttons to Expand and Collapse
`

I want each card to expand individually

Answer (score 0):

You have one big issue, the collapsed property is holding just ONE boolean value, that won't work for what you want.

The easier solution would be to create a property named activeCard (you can use index, but I'd use a different name). In there you can store the card that is currently expanded.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, AUTO_STYLE } from '@angular/animations';
import { Nutrition } from './NutritionData';

const DEFAULT_DURATION = 200;
@Component({
    selector: 'app-nutrition-report',
    templateUrl: './nutrition-report.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./nutrition-report.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger('collapse', [
            state('false', style({ height: AUTO_STYLE, visibility: AUTO_STYLE })),
            state('true', style({ height: '0', visibility: 'hidden' })),
            transition('false => true', animate(DEFAULT_DURATION + 'ms ease-in')),
            transition('true => false', animate(DEFAULT_DURATION + 'ms ease-out')),
        ])
    ]
})
export class NutritionReportComponent implements OnInit {
    Nutrition;
    activeCard;

    constructor() {
        this.Nutrition = Nutrition;
    }

    expand(index) {
        this.activeCard = index;
    }

    collapse(index) {
        this.activeCard = null;
    }

    isCardActive(index) {
      // If activeCard is null or undefined this method will always return false.
      return this.activeCard && this.activeCard === index;
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

And then, in your template you would have something like this:

```
<mat-card>
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="Content">
    <mat-card-content>
        <div [@collapse]="!isCardActive(index)" class="expandable-content" *ngIf="i === index">
        .
        .
        .
        </div>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </div>
    <mat-card-actions >
        <button *ngIf="!isCardActive(index)" (click)="expand(i)" class="mat-button">Expand</button>
        <button *ngIf="isCardActive(index)" (click)="collapse(i)" class="mat-button" >Collapse</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

That way, instead of storing a boolean flag for "collapsed", you store in memory the index of the one card that is expanded.

Comment: It's not working as expected should I switch from using index and use a variable instead?